# Is it bad to create long list of text input for translation (200 items)?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, dashboard, administration

I want to be able to let my users change the text of the web app they using, for translate and for customization.I have about 200 texts to edit.

I'm not sure if I will add a description to each text or not.

I thought that a lone infinite scrollable list, and a search box in the bottom it's enough.

I think if it is good do add a categorize filter (tabs), or something similar. The reason I'm not adding it, is beceause of someone want to transalte. either way he want to see all the text, so why to add categories?

It's not an opinion based question. I'm asking if you have and idea, how to make a long list of editable text, without categories.

[image]

Comment: I apologize but I can't properly understand your question. Do you have a visual representation of your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like the user of your app to change the text that appears on your app so that is can be written in their own language or for it to say whatever it is they want it to say. You idea was to create a long list of `input`s to accomplish this.

As for if that's "bad"... there is no good or bad in UX, just a degree of usability. Any long list is "bad" in simple terms because it's harder to use than a short one, but there might be good reason for it. If there isn't though, you should always keep things simple.

I'm assuming all this text is not on one single page in the app itself. My recommendation would be to allow each page to enter an "edit" mode, where the text that is able to be changed is replaced with a `textarea` or `input` element that the user can interact with. Once they make their changes, they can exit the edit mode and these changes are saved.

This will avoid your giant list problem, as the text will be broken down by each page.

From your screenshot, I can already tell you the list will be too long. Especially for mobile. It will be too easy for the user to get lost. Consider only using one input for each text item and just have to user write over it. That will essentially cut the length of your page in half. Additionally, breaking it up into categories as you mentioned would help a great deal, as long as the categories make sense. On top of that, you can have the user search for a particular input, meaning the list would be filterable.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is the I cannot add `edit` button to the app.
Who edit the text, is not who using the app All the text should be in a special admin dashboard.

Comment: Then allow that button to only be seen by the admin.

Comment: But there is text that that not always visible. Must be a one place for all the texts. For example: text help behid a tooltip. Error messages, etc'...

Comment: just throwing out ideas. It's up to you to decide how to apply them in the end. I can't do all your homework, so to speak, just give you tips.

Comment: If you like my answer, please select it. Thanks :)